# If $x+y+z=1$ prove $ \sqrt{x+\frac{(y-z)^{2}}{12}}+\sqrt{y+\frac{(z-x)^{2}}{12}}+\sqrt{z+\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{12}} \leq \sqrt{3} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

**Question** -

Let $x, y, z$ be non-negative real numbers which satisfies $x+y+z=1$. Prove that
$$
\sqrt{x+\frac{(y-z)^{2}}{12}}+\sqrt{y+\frac{(z-x)^{2}}{12}}+\sqrt{z+\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{12}} \leq \sqrt{3}
$$

**My work** -

First, I tried to simplify this and then now I need to prove that $\sqrt{12x+(y-z)^2}+\sqrt{12y+(z-x)^2}+\sqrt{12z+(x-y)^2} < 6 $
which I can't prove.

Then i tried jensen for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and taking weights as $x,y,z$ but it also does not work.

any hints?

thankyou

Comment: It might be possible to use some kind of symmetry argument that the max occurs when all variables are equal.

Comment: A lot of results are given by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(y-z%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7B12%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7By%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(z-x%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7B12%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bz%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(x-y%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7B12%7D%7D%5Cle%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%24).

Comment: @Ishan We can change $12$ on $8$ and it still would be true.

Comment: @Ishan   It seems that the best constant is $4 + 2\sqrt{3} \approx 7.46$;

Comment: @River Li Yes, of course. But a proof of this statement is not so nice. But for $8$ there is a nice proof.

Comment: @Saad yes i checked it before posting this question here but i did not find any nice proof there...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg did you have a nice proof of 12 ?

Comment: @Ishan Yes, I have, but with $8$, which is stronger, it's nicer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, my proof for $4 + 2\sqrt{3}$ is quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{1}{12}<\frac{1}{8},$ it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x+\frac{(y-z)^2}{8}}\leq\sqrt3.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x+\frac{(y-z)^2}{8}}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+\frac{(y-z)^2}{8}}{2x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}(2x+y+z)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4x+\frac{(y-z)^2}{2}}{2x+y+z}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4x+\frac{(y-z)^2}{2}}{2x+y+z}\leq3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{8x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2}{2x+y+z}\leq6(x+y+z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(6x-\frac{8x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2}{2x+y+z}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4x^2-y^2-z^2-2xy-2xz+2yz}{2x+y+z}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)(2x+y-z)-(z-x)(2x+z-y)}{2x+y+z}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)\left(\frac{2x+y-z}{2x+y+z}-\frac{2y+x-z}{2y+x+z}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2z(x+y)(2z+x+y)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: What is the motivation for choosing $\sum (2x+y+z)$ for C-S ?

Comment: @ArtOfProblemSolving We need to choose k for which the inequality after using C-S with $kx+y+z$ would be true. For $k=2$ it's true. This value we can get by using the fact that for $x=1$ and  $y=z=0$ the inequality is still true.